# Performed MSQL query with group by / order by

Tags: mysql

I'm working on personal inbox. Here is my inbox table :

**INBOX**

> email -- createdDate -- message
>
> mail1@test.com -- 12/02/2017 -- message1
> mail1@test.com -- 13/02/2017 -- message2
> mail3@test.com -- 14/02/2017 -- message3
> mail2@test.com -- 10/02/2017 -- message4
> mail2@test.com -- 05/02/2017 -- message5
> mail3@test.com -- 11/02/2017 -- message6
> mail3@test.com -- 16/02/2017 -- message7

What I want after the query :

> email -- createdDate -- message
> mail3@test.com -- 16/02/2017 -- message7
> mail1@test.com -- 13/02/2017 -- message2
> mail2@test.com -- 10/02/2017 -- message4

I've already tried some things with group by and order by as well as with left join but it takes SO MUCH time to be be excecuted.

My current query is :

```
SELECT a.email, a.createdDate, a.message FROM inbox a LEFT JOIN inbox b ON (a.email = b.email AND a.createdDate < b.createdDate)WHERE b.createdDate IS NULL ORDER BY a.createdDate DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

I've created indexes on my email and createdDate fields too.
Can you please help me get this result with a performing mysql query ?
thanks a lot..

Comment: Questions about performance should include a `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` and `EXPLAIN [query]`

Comment: You want the most recent email message?

Comment: yes the most recent message per mail

Comment: What happens if you have two messages on the same date from the same source? You need the time of the message as well as the date to get the most recent.

Comment: actually its not the problem here. My createdDate is a timestamp

Comment: Then you might want to adjust the example data above to reflect this.

Comment: Have you indexed the correct columns?

Comment: here is how i indexed :

> CREATE INDEX idx_createddate ON inbox (createdDate)
> ALTER TABLE inbox ADD FULLTEXT `idx_email` (`email`);

don't know if its correct...

Comment: Fulltext index is for searching **within** a field for words. What you need is a compound index on email and createdDate fields.

Comment: ok, how do you do that ?

Comment: @mcmubi have you considered searching for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your sub-query first, then just `group by` selected column:

```
select * from (select email, STR_TO_DATE(createdDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as myDate, message from inbox order by myDate desc) as t
 group by email
```

If there may be multiple email in the same date, you should have an `id` column in your table (I assume it is), then you need to add `id DESC` in the order by:

```
select * from (select email, STR_TO_DATE(createdDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as myDate, message from inbox order by myDate desc, id desc) as t
 group by email
```